# Writing to file script failed

Tags: python, scripting, error

I keep getting an error from this scrip and am unsure where I am making a mistake.

```
import bpy
import os

for ob in bpy.data.objects:
    file_object = open('blender_coordinate.txt', 'w') as f:
       f.write(ob.name)
        f.write(', ')
        f.write(ob.location)
        f.write(', ')
        f.write(ob.rotation)
        f.write('\n')
    file_object = close()
    return {'Finished'}
```

Here is the error i am recieving

```
  File "Text.py", line 5
    file_object = open('blender_coordinate.txt', 'w') as f:
                                                                                                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

location: <unknown location>:-1

Python script fail, look in the console for now...
```

I am still new to scripting and appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you mixed two methods. You can either use :

```
file_object = open('myfilename','w')
file_object.write(ob.name)
file_object.close()
```

or

```
with open('myfilename','w') as file_object:
    file_object.write(ob.name)
    #no need to close
```

The second option is better (see https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/with-statement-in-python).

Both options only require you to import bpy

Comment: Consider accepting the answer @Nburgess

Comment: I dont know how to do that.